# Is there a site to monitor Bitcoin or Altcoin addresses if funds were received or sent?

Tags: address, altcoin

Looking for a service that can email/sms you if a monitored bitcoin/altcoin address has any moved funds. Is there such a service for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [blockcypher.com's API](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/), they provide webhook callbacks (i.e. HTTPS notifications) for [different types of events](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#types-of-events), including transactions being confirmed or attaining a certain confidence level.

I think [block.io's API](https://block.io/docs/notifications) can do something similar, however that is more oriented around their own web wallet, i.e. for monitoring addresses in a wallet managed through them, rather than arbitrary addresses.

Answer (score 1):

[bitnotify.com](http://bitnotify.com/) and even [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/wallet/payment-notifications) offer such services. Note, however, that you should still go check whether you actually have received the money (which you can also do on blockchain.info) because the fact that you received a notification only means that the transaction was broadcasted, not that it made it into the blockchain, especially not that it made it into the blockchain permanently.

Comment: what about other altcoins?

Comment: @duckx I don't know about them, sorry.

Comment: You could use https://etherscan.io/ to subscribe for notification on Ethereum network, considering that is the altcoin